# Cournot duopoly market equation

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

**What does '$a$' represent in this equation?  I know what the rest means but cannot think what '$a$' represents?**

Consider a Cournot duopoly market with demand curve $ =a −$,where $ = _1 +_2$. The firm’s respective marginal costs are $_1$, $_2$.

Also does anyone have any tips on how to the reaction functions on a graph please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter $a$ is just a positive number (which needs to be greater than $c_1$ and $c_2$ for both firms to produce in equilibrium). Mathematically it is the vertical intercept of the demand curve (when $P$ is measured on the vertical axis) because when $Q=0$, $P=a$. Economically, it is the "choke price", i.e. the price where quantity demanded just becomes zero.

To find the reaction function of firm $1$, you need to find the profit-maximizing choice of $q_1$, which requires first writing down the profit function for firm $1$:
$$\pi_1(q_1,q_2)=[\underbrace{(a-q_2)-q_1}_{P}-c_1]q_1$$

The reaction function plots firm $1$'s profit-maximizing choice of $q_1$ against the quantity of the firm, $q_2$. Since the function above is quadratic in $q_1$, you can find the profit-maximizing value of $q_1$ by finding the profit function's horizontal intercepts, i.e. the $q_1$ where $\pi_1(q_1,q_2)=0$. The profit-maximizing $q_1$ will be halfway between the two intercepts (so long as the firm can make a positive profit). This is firm $1$'s reaction function. Firm $2's$ will be identical except for a change of indices.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to find the Cournot reaction functions of each firm and the Cournot-Nash equilibrium.?  Do I choose any positive number for 'a'

Comment: You do not need to choose a value for $a$. You can keep it general. An $a$ will appear in your expressions for the reaction functions. If you know how to find a monopoly's profit maximizing quantity, then you just apply the same method to find a firm's reaction function The only difference is that the price depends on both $q_1$ and $q_2$ (because $P=a-Q=a-(q_1+q_2)=(a-q_2)-q_1$ so that firm $2$'s choice of output affects the intercept of firm $1$'s residual demand curve.)

Comment: Im not getting this. Its my fault, not yours - thanks for trying to help me.  Please could show me the reaction functions of my question on a graph (so I know it is correct) and then I can refer to it as a model for me to follow.

Comment: Also, if the reaction functions of Firm 1 and Firm 2 are identical, How can it be explained that Firm 1 could make more profit than Firm 2?

Comment: You can find pictures of the reaction functions, full solutions , and video explanations for the Cournot model all over the web. Their reaction functions are not identical; they are identical except for a change of indices. If $c_1<c_2$ then firm $1$'s profits will be more than firm $2$'s in equilibrium.